# Manipulating the search schema through HTTP call

Tags: rest, web-services, online, search-schema

Using SharePoint Online, I'm looking for a way to provision through HTTP call (rest or web service) search schema configuration.

Especially, I'd like to map some RefinableStringXX to custom column after a custom process.

The process is built in Power Automate and I have to stick with HTTP call.

I don't have access to an Azure or similar subscription to hold some CSOM code (to use `SearchConfigurationPortability` class and associated).

Is there any way ?

Thx

As a workaround, I consider reproducing a CSOM HTTP call using `client.svc/processquery` endpoint. Using fiddler to grab a sample call, I may be able to reach my goal. The endpoint is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-csom/18c961c7-8384-4493-8227-54a3fffdc7cc) but I'm not sure if it's a supported scenario.

Comment: It seems to be impossible. Here is a similar question for your reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241438/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-edit-search-schema-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Actually, I found a possible workaround (see my edit). But I'm not sure it's a supported way